# Is it possible to expand a property of a blazor component?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to *expand* the property `Items` in my `TabControl` component.

So instead of

```
<TabControl Items="@MyListOfItems" />
```

I want to open or expand the property - not sure what to call this - and add my items directly instead of using a list and defining it as vanilla c# in my code behind or @code block

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Items>
        <TabItem Title="foo">
            content for my <strong>foo</strong> page
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Title="bar">
            content for my <strong>bar</strong> page
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl.Items>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: If I understand.... and if your tab items are always the same, you could use a dictionary instead of a list where the key is the title. Then you could build each TabItem manually but make the content pull from the dictionary. I'm not really seeing a reason to do that, but if that's what you want.

Comment: Have you looked at Steve Sanderson's (one of the primary authors of Blazor) example?  https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/f10a552e1761ff759b1631d81a4428c3  That's how I implement my tab control, and it's also a general solution for the sort of situation you are describing here.  (using interfaces to coordinate between the two kinds of components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can do this. You will create a parent component, let's call it `TabSet.razor`. Then inside that component you will need to have a `RenderFragment` as a `[Parameter]` to handle the child components. Then you will need a `Tab.razor` component to handle the actual tab content/title. Here's a **very** brief overview. But see the link below for the full code sample from Microsoft.

TabSet.Razor

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs @CssClasses">
    @ChildContent
</ul>
```

```cs
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
```

Usage:

```html
<TabSet TabChange="TabChanged" @ref="_menuTabSet" CssClasses="mr-auto">
    <Tab Title="Dashboard" URI="Dashboard" />
    <Tab Title="Create Portfolio" URI="Portfolio/Create" />
    <Tab Title="Search" URI="Search" />
    <Tab Title="Sentiment Profiler" URI="SentimentProfiler" />
    <Tab Title="Using EDGE" URI="Help" />
    <Tab Title="Data Science" URI="DataScience" />
</TabSet>
```

Tab.razor

```html
<li class="@TabActiveClass">
    @Title
</li>
```

```cs
[Parameter]
public string Title { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string TabActiveClass { get; set; }
```

There *was* a fantastic Microsoft guide for this but they replaced it with a Table example instead, however here is the historical reference to that guide: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/d5b7249fd16715a045d0077d147341d95c7f17bf/aspnetcore/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters.md#tabset-example